# invalid object name 'tableName' error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc, database-connection

I am using SQL Server 2005. I am getting this error while connecting with sql server from java. Using SQL Server Authentication. Login:sa Table name=Task

```
[microsoft][odbc sql server driver][sql server]invalid object name 'Task'
```

Below is the connection code in java file in try-catch block.

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dsndbPMA;");
st=conn.createStatement();
query="select * from Task";
rs=st.executeQuery(query);
```

Can anyone please help me where I have mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the connection isn't attaching to the correct database. Can you posy the connection string? Does the connection string specify the data source?

Comment: Thanks for your help..Sorry due to certain reasons I have just switched to the older database where everything was working properly.